# Using each() not working in this simple example

Tags: jquery

I am trying to understand how to use jquery's each(), because what I tried so far is not working.

In my example I am trying to use `.each()` to add a border to the *first element* when any 'special' div is clicked. The next time a 'special' div is clicked, add a border to the *second* 'special' element. Third time any 'special' div is clicked add a border to the *third element,* etc...

JS

```
$.each(function(i) {
     $('.special').click(function(){
         $('.special[i]').css('border','2px solid red');
     }
     i++;
});
```

HTML

```
    <div class="special">fooft1</div>
    <div class="special">fooft2</div>
    <div class="special">fooft3</div>
    <div class="special">fooft4</div>
    <div class="special">fooft5</div>
    <div class="special">fooft6</div>
```

Comment: No need for `.each()` here

Comment: thanks for the reply, why is each() not appropriate here?

Comment: When you attach the `.click` to the class `.special`it automatically attaches it to **all** of the elements that have the `.special` class

Comment: See my answer below http://jsfiddle.net/videsignz/T8wvS/

Comment: Please see edited post, I was unable to solve this.

Comment: Can I see the html that goes with it?

Comment: Is there a reason you cant do it like this? http://jsfiddle.net/videsignz/T8wvS/2/

Comment: In your example, all input fields are enabled, which is not what I need.

Comment: Can you explain how it 'should' work? I didnt mess with your html, just the jquery.

Comment: Are they all supposed to be disabled? If so, how will you trigger `.on('change')` ? Or are youlooking to have the first input enabled then enable the next input after the first one is changed, so on and so on?

Comment: Like this? Some input would help man http://jsfiddle.net/videsignz/T8wvS/14/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var i = 0;
$('.special').click(function(){
         $(".special:eq("+i+")").css('border','2px solid red');
     }
     i++;
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Can you please see edited post, I was unable to apply this logic to my code successfully.

Answer (score 1):

You don't want `each` for this:

```
(function() {
    var nextIndex = 0;

    $(".special").click(function() {
        $('.special').eq(nextIndex).css('border','2px solid red');
        ++nextIndex;
    });

})();
```

*(The reason for the wrapping function is that I don't want to make `nextIndex` a global. If your code is **already** inside a function, you don't need the extra wrapper.)*

Or if the specials aren't dynamic, you can remember them between calls if you want:

```
(function() {
    var nextIndex = 0,
        specials = $(".special");

    specials.click(function() {
        specials.eq(nextIndex).css('border','2px solid red');
        ++nextIndex;
    });

})();
```

You might also want some behavior if you go past the last one, like removing the handler or similar.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Can you please see edited post, I was unable to apply this logic to my code :/

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
var i = 0;
$('.special').click(function() {
    $('.special').eq(i).css('border', '2px solid red');
    i++;
});
```

Working [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/videsignz/T8wvS/)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This works for borders however, can you please see edited post, I was unable to apply this logic to my code.

Answer (score 1):

`.each()` is an iterating function. It's usefull as a replacement for a `for each` statement.

Also, your second selector isn't right `'.special[i]'` this will not be interpreted by jQuery. To make it work you would have to concatenate the variables `'.special[' + i + ']'`. This will make your code add the border to every element in the set.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('div.special').each(function(i,e) {
    $(this).click(function() {
        if($(this).hasClass('current')) {
            $(this).css('border', '1px solid red').removeClass('current');
            $(this).next().addClass('current');
        }
   });        
});

<div class="special current">fooft1</div>
<div class="special">fooft2</div>
<div class="special">fooft3</div>
<div class="special">fooft4</div>
<div class="special">fooft5</div>
<div class="special">fooft6</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/v7gJF/

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Not exactly what I need. Does not work when you click on ANY special div to add the border.

Comment: I updated the HTML, when page load, you should have class current on first div ;)

Comment: still not working correctly haha :) you're jquery should add a border to the next 'special' element, every time ANY special element is clicked, which it doesn't.